# How Google Docs hook the Ctrl-F hotkey?

Tags: javascript

In google docs, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the browser will not pop up the "Find" dlg, but the google docs will get this event, how to make it technology?

Comment: and it doesn't work very well, at least on Firefox 7, first you've to be sure that everything is completely loaded or you'll have the browser search, second you've to click in the page, sometimes try and re-try multiple times before getting the right search. I find this behaviour quite annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess that they [bind an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) that fires when a key is pressed. If <kbd>F</kbd> and [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are pressed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent#Attributes) (see `charCode`, `keyCode`, and `ctrlKey`) then they can [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) — preventing the browser-default "Find" interface — and instead render their own in-browser "Find" UI.

---

Of course, this wouldn't be fun without the usual hodgepodge of browser inconsistencies. That means if you're taking the (**strongly not recommended)** no-library route, you might want to read up on [the differences on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html).

Comment: In Chrome at least, if you call `e.preventDefault()` on the `keydown` event on `window`, you prevent all key commands from working and the user can't type into anything. Not that this is recommended :)

Comment: You would only `preventDefault` if the right key combination was pressed. Or are you saying that: even doing so conditionally breaks all key commands? (Remember that Google Docs does provide a bunch of [other keyboard shortcuts](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=179738) as well.)

Comment: It seems that Google Docs might do more than just capture the keyboard shortcut. Try loading a large document, while the document is loading press `Ctrl + F`, the standard browser "Find..." box should open. However, once the document finishes loading, Google docs will automatically close the standard browser "Find..." box.

I checked in Chrome and the box automatically closes when opening a a document in Google Docs, but the box does not automatically close on other web pages when the page finishes loading.